# Textblock ui not updating Mvvm c#

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I guess my problem has something to do with the databinding:

My.xaml adding viewmodel:

```
 <Grid.Resources>
            <vm:FreeTrainingViewModel x:Key="FreeTrainingViewModel"></vm:FreeTrainingViewModel>
        </Grid.Resources>
```

My .xaml Textblock:

```
  <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe WP Black" FontSize="300" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding PushupsCount, Source={StaticResource FreeTrainingViewModel}}"  ></TextBlock>
```

My Viewmodel:

```
 public class FreeTrainingViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _pushupsCount;

    public int PushupsCount
    {
        get { return _pushupsCount; }
        set { _pushupsCount = value; OnPropertyChanged("_pushupsCount"); Debug.WriteLine("Triggered PropertyChanged"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }        
}
```

Code behind my view:

```
    public sealed partial class FreeTraining : Page
    {
        FreeTrainingViewModel FreeTrainingViewModel = new FreeTrainingViewModel();
        public FreeTraining()
        {               
            this.InitializeComponent();
        } //Method for adding +1 to the pushupsCount "FreeTrainingViewModel.PushupsCount+1;"
}
```

The PropertyChangedEvent is getting triggered, the property is changing fine, but the textblock isn't updating.

I don't know what is wrong. Help me to find the bug pls.

Comment: Try setting , Mode=TwoWay

Comment: Try to set UpdateSourceTrigger property in xaml like this: ` Text="{Binding ..., UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Comment: @Sajeetharan It doesn't work

Comment: @RedOne Doesn't work either

Comment: In the setter for your Prop try doing PushupsCount instead of _pushupsCount. You want your Prop in there not your field

Comment: @Brandon yep changed it, but it is not the only bug...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems on your code:

1. You need to call the OnPropertyChanged with your property name ("PushupsCount") instead of your private member name ("_pushupsCount")
2. You create 2 instances of FreeTrainingViewModel:

   - One in the Grid resources. This one is binding with the TextBlock
   - One in FreeTraining. You are trying to update this.
     You need to use the same instance at 2 places.

In your .xaml file:

```
<Grid x:Name="gridName">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <vm:FreeTrainingViewModel x:Key="FreeTrainingViewModel"></vm:FreeTrainingViewModel>
    </Grid.Resources>
</Grid>
```

In your code behind:

```
public sealed partial class FreeTraining : Page
{
    FreeTrainingViewModel FreeTrainingViewModel;
    public FreeTraining()
    {               
        this.InitializeComponent();
        FreeTrainingViewModel = (FreeTrainingViewModel)gridName.FindResource("FreeTrainingViewModel");
    } //Method for adding +1 to the pushupsCount "FreeTrainingViewModel.PushupsCount+1;"
```

}

Comment: I added the viewmodel to the page.resources , i'm developing a windows universal app, so there is no findresource method available - I understand now that I create 2 instances of the FreeTrainingViewModel, so I deleted the c# code behind the page, can't I access the viewmodel by using the key in c#? Like FreeTrainingsViewmodel.Property = ...

Comment: I haven't worked with Universal app. But I believe you can get the resource instance in your code behind like following: gridName.Resources["FreeTrainingViewModel"]. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references